# React Native - Parse Large JSON Files Without Clogging JS Thread

Tags: json, react-native

I am building a RN app, and in the app I need to parse large JSON files. Since JSON.parse runs on the JS thread the entire thread gets clogged, especially on slower android devices, completely freezing the app.
On web I could just use web workers to do these tasks but this is not possible on RN. I have tried using the interaction manager but this isn't too much help because once it starts parsing the app just freezes. I was sure there would be some JSON.parse JSI lib but couldn't find any.

Any solutions or direction are greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!